# Which PayPal notification should I wait for to open and cancel a user's license?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-subscriptions

https://www.paypal.com/ca/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/acc/ipn-subscriptions-outside

Paypal has 6 different txn_types. I assume on "subscr_signup", I have the first payment in my hand and I can send their license. Then lets say halfway through the subscription they cancel, I will get the "subscr_cancel" notification? Then at the end of their paid period, I get the "subscr_eot" notification. Is this correct?

Therefor, in a recurring billing system, I just need to create a license on "subscr_signup" and delete a license on "subscr_eot"? Is there anything I'm missing? I just don't want to rip the buyer off.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I assume on "subscr_signup", I have the first payment in my hand and I can send their license.

No. You can get `subscr_signup` and `subscr_payment` in either order. You shouldn't send anything until you have the money. If doing that requires what's in the signup transaction, that means you need both transactions before you can do anything. In my system I create the user on signup, but I only give him his permissions and send him an email only if both transactions have occurred.

> Then lets say halfway through the subscription they cancel, I will get the "subscr_cancel" notification?

Correct.

> Then at the end of their paid period, I get the "subscr_eot" notification. Is this correct?

Yes. You don't need to do anything particular about `subscr_cancel`. All I do is send him an email asking if there is anything we can do to retrieve the situation.

> Therefore, in a recurring billing system, I just need to create a license on "subscr_signup" and delete a license on "subscr_eot"?

Not quite, see above.

> Is there anything I'm missing? I just don't want to rip the buyer off.

You need to handle `subscr_modify.` I handle it by terminating the current subscription as for `subscr_eot` using the effective date supplied as the end date, and starting a new one as for subscr_signup` using the effective date as the new start date.

When you check for payments, e.g. on `subcr_signup`, you also need to look out for payment failures, reversals, etc, to make sure you've really received the money. You have to to check the `payment_status.` I also have some logic somewhere to make sure the last transaction on the account isn't a reversal.

Comment: I should be able to merge subscr_signup and subscr_payment. Instead of watching for signup, I'll watch for payment and if the payment email doesn't have a license yet, that means I haven't processed it yet. So I can ignore signup notifications if I do it that way.